# Different icon on multiply custom post( acf+google map )

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to implement google maps by acf and everything works like a charm except one thing. I would like to have main icon different than other and icon will be uploaded by acf. Thanks for any hint.

Here is bunch of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var locations = [<?php while( $wp_query->have_posts() ){
$wp_query->the_post();
$location = get_field('carte_google');?>

['<?php the_title(); ?> <br/> <?php  the_field('map_description'); ?> <?php  the_field('pin'); ?>', <?php echo $location['lat']; ?>, <?php echo $location['lng'];?>, <?php $NUM++ ?>],<?php } ?> ];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 3,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.7830954, 24.0697979),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var image = {
         url: 'probably here should be image from acf',
};
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

Thank You for Your help in advance.

Comment: Where you says 'probably here should be image from acf' is correct. You just retrieve the image uri from acf and put there.

Comment: Yes, I know but  how? I tried a lot of different ways. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible solutions.

1 - Create categories and set the post with these categories (this is useful to when you has many places in map with the same icon)

2 - Create a custom field to place the icon

I will describe both.

By creating categories you can easily to link many locations with the same icon. I did it once and used the [categories images plugin](https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/categories-images/). When in loop, just identify the post category and retrieve image for it, something like:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    var image = '<?php echo z_taxonomy_image($term_id); ?>';
    // the $term_id is the category from the current post in loop that 
    // you need to retrieve

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
});
```

With the second solution you must to create an Advanced Custom Field for some post/page type, this custom field will be of type: "image". Set the return to be the **image URI**, not an object as is the default option. For this example, I suppose that you will create a field named **map_icon**. In your question I can see you already have a custom field named **map_description**, for this same ACF configuration just add the image custom field. And to show this image you can do this:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    var image = '<?php the_field('map_icon', $post_id); ?>';
    // the $post_id is the current post in loop

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
});
```

Has a lot of time since I did this, but looking in some references like [ACF](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) and the Categories Images plugin these 2 solutions must to work to you.

Answer (score 0):

At least I figure out how to display different icon for one post(Head-quarter - pin) and other for the rest projects. Here is code I used and it work for me. Maybe it will be useful for someone else.

I am ordering here post from the oldest to the newest and then I am adding prefix + image.png to the oldest post.

Thank You for Yours posts

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
      type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php
      $args = array(
          'post_type'       => 'projects',
          'posts_per_page'  => -1,
          'order' => 'ASC'
         );
        // query
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        $NUM = 0;
?>
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var locations = [<?php while( $wp_query->have_posts() ){
$wp_query->the_post();
$location = get_field('carte_google');?>
['<?php the_title(); ?> <br/> <?php  the_field('map_description'); ?>', <?php echo $location['lat']; ?>, <?php echo $location['lng'];?>, <?php $NUM++ ?>],
```

];

```
 var stylowanie = [ { "featureType": "water", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "on" }, { "color": "#46bcec" } ] },{ "featureType": "landscape", "stylers": [ { "color": "#f2f2f2" } ] } ];
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: Math.ceil(Math.log2($(window).width())) - 8,
  minZoom: Math.ceil(Math.log2($(window).width())) - 8,
  maxZoom: Math.ceil(Math.log2($(window).width())) - 8,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.7830954, 24.0697979),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  styles: stylowanie,

});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
 var iconURLPrefix = 'http://link.to.your.images.folder/images';

var icons = [
  iconURLPrefix + 'image1.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'image2.png',


]
var iconsLength = icons.length;
var marker, i;
var iconCounter = 0;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map,
    icon: icons[iconCounter],
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,


  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));

  // We only have a limited number of possible icon colors, so we may have to restart the counter
  if(iconCounter > iconsLength) {
    iconCounter = 0;
  }
  else{
    iconCounter = 1;
  }

}
```

I hope it will work for You as well